# AGOL hosted feature service returns more features than maxRecordCount

Tags: r, r-sf, arcgis-online

I'm doing some experiments with ArcGIS Online hosted feature services in R using the sf package.

I cannot figure out why the response of this request contains more than 60k features:
https://services.arcgis.com/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/ArcGIS/rest/services/Rijksmonumenten/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=%2A&returnCountOnly=false&f=geojson

According to the service parameters maxRecordCount is 10000:
https://services.arcgis.com/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/ArcGIS/rest/services/Rijksmonumenten/FeatureServer/0?f=json

I thought I had to use pagination, but that does not seem to be the case. Thus I'm supprised. Can somebody please explain.

This is a link to my gist containing the R code:
https://gist.github.com/FrieseWoudloper/47f4dcf68be39bff9dfaf2cd57610db3

Regards,
Willy

Comment: That first URL gets me a file with 10,000 records if I download it using `curl` or `wget` from the command line.

Comment: I suspect `st_read` is doing the pagination for you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `wireshark` network packet inspector, and changing the protocol scheme to `http` from `https`, you can see that `st_read` is doing the pagination for you, and doing 7 requests to the server to get all the data. Each request has a different request offset and then the resulting sets of 10,000 records plus the last few are concatenated.

The GeoJSON driver of OGR is doing this so `sf` gets it for free. I suspect its controlled by the FEATURE_SERVER_PAGING option documented here:

https://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html#

(Note I switched to http since its clearer to see what's going on with an unencrypted channel, the same thing happens with https)

Comment: Thank you very much @Spacedman! I'm sorry I didn't get back to you sooner, but I was camping for three weeks with hardly any WiFi...